# Optimising a repeating code in when expression Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, optimization, expression

One of my methods returns a boolean value according to the elements of a list whose size can go from 0 to 4. I used a `when` expression, but the "problem" is the repetition (redundancy) of my code. Here it is:

```
list.apply {
    return when (size) { //size in 0..4
        0 -> false
        1 -> get(0) == 9
        2 -> get(0) == 9 || get(0) == get(1) || get(0) + get(1) == 8
        3 -> get(0) == 9 || get(0) == get(1) || get(0) + get(1) == 8 || get(0) == get(2) || get(0) + get(2) == 8
        else -> get(0) == 9 || get(0) == get(1) || get(0) + get(1) == 8 || get(0) == get(2) || get(0) + get(2) == 8 || get(0) == get(3) || get(0) + get(3) == 8 // when size == 4
    }
}
```

As you can see, the below code have many repetitions. I found another solution, and this one almost doesn't repeat itself, but I have the impression that it is possible to shorten the code (maybe I'm wrong?). Here is the other version (still in the inline function `apply`) :

```
var rtn = false
if (size > 0) rtn = rtn || get(0) == 9
if (size > 1) rtn = rtn || get(0) == get(1) || get(0) + get(1) == 8
if (size > 2) rtn = rtn || get(0) == get(2) || get(0) + get(2) == 8
if (size > 3) rtn = rtn || get(0) == get(3) || get(0) + get(3) == 8
return rtn
```

Is there any way to shorten or optimize the code a bit more? And among these 2 versions, which one is to be preferred and why?

Comment: your second piece of code does not seem to affect your `returnValue`. It will always be false, is that intended?

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to rename the variable correctly... Updated ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```kotlin
val result = with(list) {
    isNotEmpty() && (first() == 9 || (1..lastIndex).any { first() == get(it) || first() + get(it) == 8 })
}
```

Comment: what about that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when there are 4 elements in the list?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know the inline `any` function at all (I only used `apply` and `let`...).